# Storing windows path in MySQL without escaping backslashes

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to store windows path in MySQL without escaping the backslashes. How can I do this in Python? I am using MySQLdb to insert records into the database. When I use MySQLdb.escape_string(), I notice that the backslashes are removed.

Comment: "I notice that the backslashes are removed."  How -- specifically -- do you "notice" this.  Include the code you're using to view the path.  This may be doing something wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem. You notice it by doing a select again from the table and see the \ are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at   `os.path.normpath(thePath)`

I can't remember if it's that one, but there IS a standard os.path formating function that gives double backslashes, that can be stored in a db "as is" and reused later "as is". I have no more windows machine and cannot test it anymore.

Comment: os.path.normpath Does not work, I don't think you need windows machine, you can just try to insert a string containing backslashes and see it disappear from the column.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dictionary to add slashes wherever required to make the query valid :

http://codepad.org/7mjbwKBf

```
def addslashes(s):
    dict = {"\0":"\\\0", "\\":"\\\\"}  #add more here
    return ''.join(dict.get(x,x) for x in s)

query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE id,path values(23,'c:\windows\system\')";

print(addslashes(query));
```

Answer (score 0):

After 11 years and 7 months, I can say one way is to first replace all the \ with a special character - say, a tab, (`file_path.replace('\\','\t')`) then, have MySQL convert it back into a char(92), which is a backslash (`REPLACE('{log_file_name}',CHAR(9),CHAR(92)`).

eg, from:

```
    sql="INSERT INTO df_log (file_path) VALUES ('{log_file_name}');".format(file_path=file_path))
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

to:

```
    sql="INSERT INTO df_log (file_path) VALUES (REPLACE('{log_file_name}',CHAR(9),CHAR(92));".format(file_path=file_path.replace('\\','\t')))
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```