# Backslash gets stripped from string when trying to insert into mysql column using python

Tags: python, mysql

As per title, when I try to insert a string containing backslashes they get removed. Say I have the following statement:

filename="D:\myfiles\log files\2022-12-05 11-33-31.dat"

then I insert it into my MySQL table with the following:

```
        sql="INSERT INTO df_log (log_file_name,file_hash) VALUES ('{log_file_name}');".format(log_file_name=(log_file_name))
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
```

It executes happily but then when I do a select from the database, I see:

```
D:myfileslog files2022-12-05 11-33-31.dat
```

All the \ are missing. I've tried double backslash to try to escape it, but still no luck.

This is similar to [Convert a string to literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327214/convert-a-string-to-literal-type) and [Storing windows path in MySQL without escaping backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553200/storing-windows-path-in-mysql-without-escaping-backslashes) but nobody seems to understand the question or able to replicate the issue.